# Discord.py: How to Ping User Through a User ID Variable

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a queue system bot, BUT I need to store the author name/id. So I have 2 commands. One when the number of queues is 0 and 1. I can easily use `message.author.mention` but how would I ping the first id (the one where queue = 0) in the same message.

Code:

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

#run the Bot and a message to make sure it ran
client = discord.Client()

global queue
queue = 0
global author
author = " "
global author2
author2 = " "

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Minceraft'))

@client.event
async def on_message(message): #Defines Message
  
  #If You Queue, And Role Requirement to Do So
  if message.content.startswith('-queue duos'): 
    global queue
    if queue == 0:
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)

      if role in message.author.roles:

        print('you have queued')
      
        global author
        author = message.author.id
        print(author)

        #Adds Role Duos
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656) 
        await message.author.add_roles(role) 

        #Removes Role NoQueue
        role4 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)
        await message.author.remove_roles(role4)
      
        #Gives Message
        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue sit tight!')
          
        queue += 1
        
        await message.channel.send(queue)

    elif queue == 1:
      role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)

      if role in message.author.roles:

        print('you have queued')
      
        global author2
        author2 = message.author.id
        print(author2)

        #Adds Role Duos
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656) 
        await message.author.add_roles(role) 

        #Removes Role NoQueue
        role4 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)
        await message.author.remove_roles(role4)
      
        #Gives Message
        await message.channel.send('you have joined the duos queue sit tight!')
        queue += 1
        

        #Work On Pings Here
        
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention)
        await message.channel.send(author)
        queue = 0

    #Is They Already Queued and Have Duos Role  
    else:
      await message.channel.send('You Already Queued!')


  #if the message is unqueue duos command
  if message.content.startswith('-unqueue duos'):
    #Role Requirement
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656)
    if role in message.author.roles:
      print('you have unqueued')
      

      #Remove Duos Role
      role2 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830219965549510656)
        
      await message.author.remove_roles(role2)
      #Adds NoQueue Role
      role3 = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=830557149863608367)

      await message.author.add_roles(role3)
    
      await message.channel.send('You Have Unqueued Duos!')
      
      queue -= 1
    #Already Not In a Queue  
    else:
        await message.channel.send('You Are Not In a Queue!')
  


#Runs Token From The .env File
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

---

TL;DR: I want to ping someone using a global string because I can't use `message.author.mention` with 2 people at once or in the same `message.channel.send` command.

Comment: If you're implementing some sort of queueing system, shouldn't you be storing the people in the queue in e.g. a list instead of... whatever it is that's happening right now?

Comment: unrelevant to the question: make your commands actual commands and not using on_message events. This is gonna be of much use later, because it's gonna be a pain for your bot to watch for "-(un)queue duos" in servers where there are many messages.

Answer (score 0):

`<@USERID>` is how you mention someone. Just get the id and change USERID for that. What you could do is:

```
await message.channel.send(f"<@{USERID}>")
```

because f strings format things for you. That code would mention someone.

Comment: I'll Try it Out! Thanks For Helping Me :D